# How do I run a command on all Workspace search matches in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to titlecase all the `<title>` content in a set of files. E.g.,

`<title>THIS</title>`

to:

`<title>This</title`

In VS Code, I've installed the `titlecase` extension which works great for multiple selections **in a single file**. But I'd to make changes in a **set** of files at once.

I can create a Workspace regex search that nicely highlights just the string in each file that needs to change. Sure, the built-in Replace will act on all matches, But I don't see way to run any chosen command from the Palette.

I've tried unsuccessfully to convert the Search matches to selections in multiple files.

I've tried to "open the search results in an editor" and run title case on that. But that is actually a completely new document, not a write-through view of some kind.

This seems like a really handy feature to have — the ability to run any Palette command on the Workspace Search matches. Have I missed something obvious?

(As a fall-back, I can re-learn how to do this with Perl.)

EDIT: Here's my workaround using a Ruby one-liner:

```bash
find . | grep index.html | xargs ruby -pe 'sub(/– ([^-]+) –/) { "- " + $1.capitalize + " -" }' -i
```

(I settled on `capitalize` in the one-liner.)

Comment: I think @rioV8 wrote an extension that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any extensions to do a find/replace across workspace files. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to show the workspace find/replace UI.Then press the little `...` icon and you can specify file name patterns to match if needed, or files to exclude.

The search box can be case sensitive if needed, or you can input a regex pattern

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to run any Palette Command of my choice across all the matches. Here, it's titlecase.